# Firebase database rewrite data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to write the user's token to the database, everything turns out for me except one, each new user overwrites the previous one. Tell me, please, what should be done to avoid this? thanks in advance

```
        const today = new Date().getFullYear();
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + today).set({
            token: token,
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include userID in the ref

```
    const today = new Date().getFullYear();
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/' + today).set({
        token: token,
    });
```